# Android ViewModel Coroutines - How to write unit test for dispatcher.IO in viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I have a viewmodel and datasource class that makes a network request. I'm trying to write a unit test that calls the viewmodel method, observe the livedata for result. However, when I run the test with debugger the test keeps passing and the response.isSuccessful line in my datasource never hits, the test ends before that line gets hit.

I'm not sure how to pause my unit test to make sure my dispatcher finishes what it's doing and I can observe my liveData. That is main issue.

Unit Test Class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TestViewModel {

    private lateinit var mockWebServer: MockWebServer
    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    private lateinit var api: TPSCallService

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Before
    fun setUp()  {
        mockWebServer = MockWebServer()
        api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("/"))
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(MyAPI::class.java)
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun testing() = runTest {
        val mockResponse = MockResponse()
        val inputStream = javaClass.classLoader?.getResourceAsStream("personalDetailsAPI/success.json")
        val source = inputStream?.let { inputStream.source().buffer() }
        mockResponse.setResponseCode(200).setBody(source!!.readString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        mockWebServer.enqueue(mockResponse)

        val dataSource = MyDataSource(api)
        val vm = MainViewModel(dataSource)
        vm.getMyList()
        vm.dataList.observeForever() {
            Assert.assertEquals("",3, it.size)
        }
    }
}
```

My Viewmodel class:

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {

    constructor(myDataSource: MyDataSource): this() {
        this.storeDataSource = storeDataSource
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MainViewModel_TAG"

        val job = SupervisorJob()
        var dispatcher = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)
    }

    private var myDataSource: MyDataSource = MyDataSource()

    private val _dataList = MutableLiveData<List<DataResponse>>()
    public val dataList: LiveData<List<DataResponse>>
        get() = _dataList

    public fun getMyList() {
        dispatcher.launch {
            myDataSource.getStoreList(Constants.DEFAULT_LATITUDE, Constants.DEFAULT_LONGITUDE) { dataLists, code ->
                _dataList.postValue(dataLists.getOrNull())// NEVER HITS!
            }
        }
    }
}

class MainViewModelFactory() :
    ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return modelClass.getConstructor()
            .newInstance()
    }
}

class MainViewModelFactoryTwo(val dataSource: MyDataSource) :
    ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return modelClass.getConstructor(MyDataSource::class.java)
            .newInstance(dataSource)
    }
}
```

My Datasource

```
class MyDataSource {

    private lateinit var myAPI: MyAPI

    constructor() {
        myAPI = NetworkModule().provideMyAPI() //Some dagger method to give me my retrofitAPI
    }

    constructor(myAPI: MyAPI) {
        this.myAPI = myAPI
    }

    public suspend fun getStoreList(lat: Double, lng: Double, completion: (Result<List<StoreResponse>>, Int) -> Unit) {
        val response = myAPI.getMyList(lat, lng).awaitResponse()

        if (response.isSuccessful) { //Break point never reaches here! TEST ENDS BEFORE REACHING HERE.
            response.body()?.let {
                completion(Result.success(it), response.code())
            } ?: run {
                completion(Result.failure(Throwable()), response.code())
            }
        } else {
            completion(Result.failure(Throwable()), response.code())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone I found a way to make the unit test pass! Here's the solution.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TestViewModel {

    private lateinit var mockWebServer: MockWebServer
    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    private lateinit var api: MyRetrofitAPI

    @get:Rule
    val coroutineTestRule = CoroutineTestRule()

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    val rxJavaRule = RxJavaRule()

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class, InternalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Before
    fun setUp()  {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        mockWebServer = MockWebServer()
        api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("/"))
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(MyRetrofitAPI::class.java)
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun `Fetch Data Test`() = runTest {
        val mockResponse = MockResponse()
        val inputStream = javaClass.classLoader?.getResourceAsStream("personalDetailsAPI/success.json")
        val source = inputStream?.let { inputStream.source().buffer() }
        mockResponse.setResponseCode(200).setBody(source!!.readString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        mockWebServer.enqueue(mockResponse)

        val dataSource = MyDataSource(api)
        val vm = MainViewModel(dataSource)
        vm.getMyList()
        vm.myList.observeForever {
            Assert.assertNotNull(it)//GETS IN HERE!
            Assert.assertEquals(2, it!!.size)
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Thread.sleep(1000L) // THE MAGIC!
        }
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        mockWebServer.shutdown()
    }
}
```